# Right way to add collection view without behaviour of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined warning

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

My requirement is to have a slider collection view on top of my view in ViewController. I've tried many work around for my requirement (You can see that in my collection view setup code). But, time I receive the warning about `The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined`. The view controller is being called from controllers array inside of a `UITabBarController` which in turn is embedded in a `UINavigtionController`. The view controller contains a collection view of height 200. I want each cell of the collection view to expand its full width and height.

Warning:

```
2017-09-06 12:05:19.139 collectionViewSample[3686:79491] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2017-09-06 12:05:19.139 collectionViewSample[3686:79491] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2017-09-06 12:05:19.140 collectionViewSample[3686:79491] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7ff4e4c00020>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7ff4e5032600; frame = (0 64; 414 200); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000047290>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000002d240>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7ff4e4c00020>.
2017-09-06 12:05:19.140 collectionViewSample[3686:79491] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

AppDelegate:

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let mainController = UITabBarController()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    mainController.viewControllers = [navController]
    window?.rootViewController = mainController
```

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    setupCollectionView()
}

func setupCollectionView() {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
    collectionView.contentInset = .zero
    collectionView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    collectionView.layoutMargins = .zero

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
}
}
```

When the cells are populated with image that fills the entire frame of the collection view it leaves a small gap on top from navigation bar. Collection view frame does extend to my requirements but the cells are not. How would I fix this the proper way?

Comment: The frame of collectionView is zero. Try to set collection view height == 200, and width > 0, because cell CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)

Comment: still the same warning

Comment: let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
try to add item size to flow layout object
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
and check is func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell get called

Comment: Ofcourse the functions are getting called. Setting just the frame doesn't seem to remove the warning.

Comment: I've tried setting all the inset properties to zero it's such a pain we have to do so much to get the default behaviour.

Comment: I checked you code on new single viewcontroller project and there is no problem. Try to create new project and to check that it works also. I use Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: It will show the warning once you make a custom UICollectionViewCell and add an image that extends the whole of collection view.

Comment: @BibinJacob What became of this?

Comment: To fix it I had to change the translucency of navigation and tab bar to false. Then adjust the size accordingly. But, I didn't get a proper fix for this issue.